# Kentico UserInfoProvider not working as expected in a console app

Tags: c#, kentico

This code works fine within a Kentico website:

```
var users = UserInfoProvider.GetUsers();
for (int x = 0; x < users.Count(); x++
{
    UserInfo currentUser = users.ElementAt(x);
    currentUser.SetValue("AcceptsAlerts", equivalentSubscriber.Status != SubscriberStatus.Unsubscribed);
    UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(currentUser);
}
```

When I move the code to a console app, any calls to UserInfoProvider result in the error: "Object type 'cms.usersettings' not found"

For the initial call to get the users, I can do it like this in the console app:

```
DataSet usersds = new CMS.DataEngine.DataQuery("cms.user.selectall").Execute();
```

then loop through Table1 of the dataset using the user data:

```
UserInfo currentUser = new UserInfo(dtUsers.Rows[x]);
```

All is fine and working, until I come to write the updated user back to the database. I cannot find another way of writing the data apart from calling:

```
UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(currentUser);
```

Does anyone know another way to save the user data? or to resolve the error. The error is a runtime error and as far as I know, I have referenced everything I need to. The field I am editing is a custom field added to the cmsUser table.

using statements for info:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using CMS;
using CMS.CustomTables;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.Membership;
```

Answer (score 5):

Before you start working with Kentico CMS API from an external application make sure you call the following lines:

```
CMS.DataEngine.ConnectionHelper.ConnectionString = "your connection string";
CMS.Base.SystemContext.WebApplicationPhysicalPath = Application.StartupPath;
CMS.DataEngine.CMSApplication.Init();
```

Then, you'll be also able to use UserInfoProvider.GetUsers() [object query](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/kentico-8-technology-dataquery-api) instead of using `DataQuery.Execute()`.

Comment: I have this code - which I think is the equivalent to yours: 
CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName = "SiteName";
CMS.DataEngine.CMSApplication.Init();
But still no luck. It gets the connection string from App.config using the sitename. Application.StartupPath isn't recognised on my system. The 2 using statements suggested by VS don't work either. what using statement do you have for this?

Comment: Hi. I've updated my answer with full qualified type names. Do not set CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName (users are global objects and even if they weren't you can always supply site parameter for site-specific objects. E.g. `RoleInfoProvider.GetRoleInfo(string roleName, int siteId)`)

Comment: _"It gets the connection string from App.config using the sitename."_ I don't know what are you talking about :) Just make sure you have the code I have provided working and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are referencing all necessary assemblies?

Following scenario works on my machine with configuration: *Kentico 8.x*, *Web Application project*

1. Reference in your Console application these assemblies from *lib* folder

   - CMS.Base
   - CMS.DataEngine
   - CMS.DataProviderSQL
   - CMS.Membership
2. Then copy your **Connection String** from Web Application's *web.config* to Console Application's *App.config*.
3. After that you can use this code to set custom user properties

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var users = UserInfoProvider.GetUsers();

       foreach (var user in users)
       {
           user.SetValue("myTestString", "test");
           user.Generalized.SetObject();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Weird! I have pretty much that! - I was missing 2 using statements - the CMS.Base and CMS.DataProviderSQL so I've added them but still get the same error when I hit the foreach loop.
var users = UserInfoProvider.GetUsers();
foreach (UserInfo u in users)
{
     Console.WriteLine(u.UserName);
}

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to get a SiteID to use in API calls from an external app such as getting an email template, this might help you.  In Kentico 8.1 you can go to Sites > General and get the code name for your site.  Then you can do this:

```
int siteID = CMS.SiteProvider.SiteInfoProvider.GetSiteID("<your site code name>");
```

Hope it helps!