# how to do API calls of Kentico using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, kentico

I'm struggling with API calls of Kentico forms using ASP.NET MVC, so that I can use AngularJS to display the return data (JSON format).

Specifically, my client is using Kentico on their server to create data using "Forms" on Kentico and I want to get the records stored in these forms via API calls using ASP.NET MVC. What I'm thinking is that in the general section of the "Forms", I see the "Form code name" showing that "Code name is a string identifier of the object that can be used by developers in API calls or URLs". But it seems to be there's no good example of it on internet. Keep trying to search it but no luck. I also tried to access data directly in SQL Server in which kentico stores the data. But the table's name that Kentico uses in SQL Server to store the data is different from the ones in "Forms" or "Custom tables" in Kentico.

Hope someone can show me how to do it and I really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very good example in the official [documentation of Kentico](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Working+with+form+data+using+the+API). 
Please note that Forms have been renamed a few times in the past (they were called BizForms and On-Line forms) that's the reason why the code below references `CMS.OnlineForms` and uses `BizFormInfoProvider`. It might also very well be the reason why you didn't find any good example :)

The example below shows how to retrieve Form's definition (metadata), get all the data and iterate through it.

```
using CMS.OnlineForms;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.SiteProvider;
using CMS.Helpers;

...

// Gets the form info object for the 'ContactUs' form
BizFormInfo formObject = BizFormInfoProvider.GetBizFormInfo("ContactUs", SiteContext.CurrentSiteID);

// Gets the class name of the 'ContactUs' form
DataClassInfo formClass = DataClassInfoProvider.GetDataClassInfo(formObject.FormClassID);
string className = formClass.ClassName;

// Loads the form's data
ObjectQuery<BizFormItem> data = BizFormItemProvider.GetItems(className);

// Checks whether the form contains any records
if (!DataHelper.DataSourceIsEmpty(data))
{
    // Loops through the form's data records
    foreach (BizFormItem item in data)
    {
        string firstNameFieldValue = item.GetStringValue("FirstName", "");
        string lastNameFieldValue = item.GetStringValue("LastName", "");

        // Perform any required logic with the form field values

        // Variable representing a custom value that you want to save into the form data
        object customFieldValue;

        // Programatically assigns and saves a value for the form record's 'CustomField' field
        item.SetValue("CustomField", customFieldValue);
        item.SubmitChanges(false);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The example above assumes that you're using the API from within the running Kentico instance. If you want to use Kentico API (DLLs)  from an external application please follow the steps I described in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325858/kentico-userinfoprovider-not-working-as-expected-in-a-console-app).

You also asked about the site identifier (siteId or siteName params of the `BizFormInfoProvider.GetBizFormInfo()` method). They refer to the `SiteInfo` object in Kentico (DB table `CMS_Site`). You can find site name if you navigate to `Site->Edit site->General->Site code name`.

If you don't want to use Kentico DLLs there is another option - using [Kentico REST endpoint](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Getting+data+using+REST).

Comment: Thanks rocky. But where to put the site name and the username and passwork to access that Kentico site? I see the code above using "SiteContext.CurrentSiteID", but I think it's just for the local host site that run locally on my PC. The site I'm accessing is from a server (Windows Azure hosting). For example, I access: http://mysite.cloudapp.net/admin/ -> login using my account -> display the admin Kentico dashboard -> forms -> see records inside forms. So I think I have to put the site name and my account somewhere in the code to get the ball rolling. Is that correct? Thanks :)

Comment: I tried: `BizFormInfo formObject = BizFormInfoProvider.GetBizFormInfo("my_form", "mysite.cloudapp.net");` but I got formObject is null. The value of "my_form" I got from the general section of that form, and value of sitename I got from: configuration->sites->choose site->general->site domain name. I think those values are correct, just somewhere to put my username and password in code.

Comment: Yeah, I got data successfully (internal Kentico). Thank you so much rocky :).

Comment: No problem. Please mark my reply as an answer to your question. Thx

Comment: Dear rocky, could you tell me how I can get all of the options of a particular DropDownListControl in the form? For example, the product form has the DropDownList category with 4 options: hot water, heating, cooking and outdoor, how to get all of these options? I can get only 1 value of category for each record in the above answer. Plus, is it possible to create a form based on the data of custom tables? So that the category gets its options from custom table instead of inserting them manually in form. And I also really apologize for asking too many question cause I'm new in Kentico. Thank you

Comment: As this is unrelated to the original topic, please create a new question. I'll try to answer it asap