# What causes "Object type 'cms.licensekey' not found" exceptions when querying Kentico blog posts from an external application?

Tags: c#, kentico

When querying Kentico 8 blog posts from an external (desktop) application, I get an exception:

> [ObjectQueryBase.Object]: Object type 'cms.licensekey' not found.

I can query pages, site settings and so on without any issues.

Code:

```
CMSApplication.Init();
DataSet posts = BlogHelper.GetBlogPosts(siteName, aliasPath, null, true, null, null, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means Kentico wasn't able to **initialize the module** that contains the definition of the `cms.licensekey` object type. In this case, we're talking about the Licensing module which is contained within the `CMS.LicenseProvider.dll` assembly.

This can typically be caused by inability to locate the DLL itself or one of it's dependencies (or their dependencies, recursively).

In Kentico 10, the dependencies are:

- CMS.Core
- CMS.Base
- CMS.DataEngine
- CMS.Helpers
- CMS.IO
- CMS.EventLog
- CMS.MacroEngine
- Mono.Cecil

You have to make sure all of them (and of course the CMS.LicenseProvider itself) are present in the `bin` folder of your app.

But there's a **better way** - you can use [Kentico.Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentico.Libraries/) NuGet package and it'll bring in all the necessary [dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentico.Libraries.Dependencies/) for you. **Follow the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/using-the-kentico-api-externally).**

Comment: The earliest version on NuGet (9) throws errors connecting to our v8 DB. Referencing Mono.Cecil throws a different error, so progress! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great. There is a version consistency check that makes sure major and minor version of assemblies match the DB version. There's no point trying v8.1 DLLs with v8.0 DB...Hotfix version, however, is ignored as there are never breaking any changes. So you can use v8.1.30 DLLs with v8.1.15 DB.

Comment: Also, make sure the `Init()` call is the first call to Kentico libraries. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34977815/1332034 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325858/kentico-userinfoprovider-not-working-as-expected-in-a-console-app/28327813#28327813

Answer (score 0):

There were several bugs fixed in v8.1 and v8.2 related to blogs and licensing so I'd suggest hotfixing to the latest hotfix of v8.x to help mitigate any of the issues you are having.

Go to the [DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes) and search in the Fixed bugs for v8 for "Blog" and you will see the problems.